# If $f\in L^2([0,1]^2)$, what can we say about $g(x)=f(x,x)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose that $L^2([0,1]^2)$ is the space of equivalence classes of square integrable functions $f:[0,1]^2\to\mathbb R$ with the usual norm given by
$$
\|f\|_2=\biggl(\int_0^1\int_0^1|f(x,y)|^2dxdy\biggr)^{1/2}.
$$
With an abuse of notation, the function and the equivalence class is denoted by the same symbol $f$ (instead of using $f$ for the function and $[f]$ for its equivalence class).

> Suppose that $f\in L^2([0,1]^2)$ and set $g(x)=f(x,x)$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. What can we say about $g$? Can we say that $g\in L^2([0,1])$?
>
> Suppose that $f,f_1,f_2,\ldots\in L^2([0,1]^2)$ such that $f_n\to f$  as $n\to\infty$ in $L^2([0,1]^2)$. Set $g(x)=f(x,x)$, $g_1=f_1(x,x),g_2=f_2(x,x),\ldots$ for each $x\in[0,1]$. Can we say that $g_n\to g$ as $n\to\infty$ in $L^2([0,1])$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is true, the diagonal in $[0,1]^2$ has measure zero, so $f(x,x)$ can do whatever it wants without changing its norm in $L^2([0,1]^2)$.

Comment: Indeed, for eeach equivalence class in $L^2([0,1]^2)$, the function $g$ can be chosen at will.

Comment: Although, indeed, there is no restriction map from $L^2$ of a square to $L^2$ of its diagonal, there _is_ a slightly fancier version which succeeds: as a simple example of a (keyword=) "trace theorem", if $f\in L^2([0,1]^2)$ _and_ if its (distributional!) first partial derivatives are also in $L^2$, then "restriction to diagonal" is a continuous map from that Sobolev space to $L^2$ of the diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no as indicated in the comments above, here is simply a more detailed answer. Let $[\tilde{f}]\in L^2([0,1]^2)$, here $[\tilde{f}]$ denotes the class of all functions equal to $\tilde{f}$ up to sets of measure zero. Define a map $f(x,y)$ by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
\tilde{f}(x,y) & \mbox{ if } x\neq y,\\
+\infty & \mbox{ if } x=y.
\end{cases}$$
Then $[f]=[\tilde{f}]$ but the function $g(x):=f(x,x)=+\infty$ is not $L^2$-integrable.

Comment: A minor quibble: I might recommend (for pedagogical, not technical) reasons to not denote your auxiliary function with a prime, as in an analysis context that's usually reserved for derivatives. Something like $f_1$ or $\stackrel{\sim}{f}$ might be superior.

Comment: @AdamHughes: You're right, I hadn't thought about that.